# Build identical ubuntu kernel packages

Tags: kernel, compiling

I compile my own patched version of the upstream linux-kernel. Until now I have always used `make-kpkg`, by running

```
CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=9 fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-patched kernel_image kernel_headers kernel_debug.
```

(I have read about the `kernel_debug` target somewhere in the past, but it does not seem to be documented)
What I want are packages that behave and do exactly what the respective ubuntu packages do, since this does not seem to be the case. 
The above command creates the kernel headers package, but virtualbox dkms simply skips the build of the module for this kernel since it can not find the sources (I checked, they are present in /usr/src).

I need a debug package of my compiled kernel too, since kdump and other debugging tools require that and I would really like it to be a ubuntu package and  it seems the created dbg package is rather small.

Apart from image, headers and debug (via the ddebs repository) ubuntu seems to offer linux-image-extra and linux-tools packages, which I could not find to be any target of `make-kpkg, are those automatically integrated?

So how could I build all those packages I need?

**EDIT:** I have found out the following:

1. For the debug package, you need to have `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y` in your kernel configuration along with the `kernel_debug` target.
2. For the dmks not finding kernel sources: It seems `make-kpkg` is not meant to create packages for others than yourself, since the package creates links to the build directory which is insane if you ask me and if you delete your build directory the headers package will be completely broken since link in `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/build` points to the build directory.

Is there a better method than `make-kpkg` because I don not need a tool that creates packages, that contain links that point to the build directory. Why would anybody need a tool that automates stuff and you need to fix it afterwards?

Comment: Okay I have tested `make deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom` and it build all packages I need, but the -dbg package is 75MB and the linux-image is 750MB, it should be the other way around. any ideas?